# Is it possible to create child processes in node.js which do not exit when their parents do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Is it possible to create child processes in node.js which do not exit when their parents do?

I'm running node v0.6.19.

Comment: Do you want to demonize the process?

Comment: Actually, I've created a set of processes which communicate together (IPC and RPC) to perform a task, and I want to run a script to initialize them based on some config file. The thing is, I don't want the script to run forever, I want it to exit after having created the necessary processes.

Comment: So I guess you could say I want to daemonize the child processes I want to create, yes.

Comment: No. it is not possible because each process of node.js is event loop. That would be fundamentally against event loop nature.

Comment: Search for a `npm` package that fit you needs. There are plenty of them available (at least if you are on a *nix system). - [npm search](http://search.npmjs.org/) - [Nipster](http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/#daemon) (npm + github)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use `child_process.spawn` and pass the `detached` option, then call `child.unref()`.

Make sure you read the notes: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.

```
npm install daemon
```

test1.js:

```
var
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    test2 = spawn('node', ['test2.js']);

    console.log(test2.pid);
```

test2.js:

```
var daemon = require('daemon');
daemon.start();

setInterval(function() {
    // do something
}, 1000);
```

test1.js will spawn test2.js and exit. test2.js will continue to work in the background.